# Nativescript & Angular component inheritance structure

Tags: angular, inheritance, mobile, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm making a gallery of a few mini-games, and I figured out how to make the gallery populated with dynamically loaded components based on the [NativeScript/sample-groceries github repo](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries).  So I have:

> ./game.ts

```
export class Game { 
    constructor( public title: string, public link: string )
}
```

> ./components/gallery/gallery.component.ts

```
import { Game } from "../game"
export class GalleryComponent{
    public games = [ new Game("testGame1", "/testGame1"), ... ]
}
```

And then I display the games using a loop inside `gallery.component.html`.  However each game shares some basic structure:

1. afterwards it will collect data on the user's play style,
2. if it was a win or lose,
3. account information.

then send all this to my website API for storage and processing.  This sounds like an inheritance problem, so [I did some research](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/generator/extend-class-interface) and now i'm thinking I could have a `Class Game` which has these methods to interact with the API, while each `Class Mini-Game extends Game` simply is in charge of determining if it was a win/lose and adding any game specific meta-data.

This is where i'm stuck though, do I still need to tie each `Mini-Game` to `app.module` and `app.routing`?

Secondly can these components work as routers themselves? Such that `Gallery` or `Game` would be incharge of loading a sub-component's `mini-game.ts/.html` to load?  I was thinking

```
|-gallery.component/
  |-css/html/ts
  |-game.component/
     |-ts                     # class definition
     |-minigame1.component/   # extends game.component
       |-css/html/ts
     |-minigame2.component/   # extends game.component
       |-css/html/ts
```

Comment: I would approach this by using services for the common problems (the three points) and then using the Angular Dependency Injection to reuse those services in my mini-games.

Comment: Regarding the loading of sub-components - yeah you can implement lazy loading - not only it will boost your startup performance but also will allow you to create inner routes https://www.nativescript.org/blog/optimizing-app-loading-time-with-angular-2-lazy-loading